# Can't find the property of an extended class via generics

Tags: typescript

**Updated:**

My intent is to make an abstract class that can be used as the `Base Model` of a `ORM`. The static method `method` is something like `find an instance of that model` and should create the instance itself...

This is what I had in mind (the generic "T" is required in the class definition to have the typing on the constructor argument):

```
abstract class Model<T extends Model<T>> {
  static property;

  static method<T extends Model<T>>(this: (new () => T)): T {
    console.log(this.property); // TS2339: Property 'property' does not exist on type 'new () => T'

    return new this();
  }

  constructor(item?: Partial<T>) {
    Object.assign(this, item);
  }
}

class User extends Model<User> {
  email: string;
}

const user = User.method();
user.email = 'foo';
```

Instead the following is what was suggested (without the generic):

```
abstract class Model1 {
  static property;

  static method() {
    console.log(this.property);

    return new this(); // TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
  }

  constructor(item?) { // No clues on the properties of "item"
    Object.assign(this, item);
  }
}

class User1 extends Model1 {
  email: string;
}

const user1 = User1.method();
user1.email = 'foo'; // TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type Model1
```

**Original question 2019-04-10**

I've the following piece of code:

```
class Model<T extends Model<T>> {
  static property;

  static method<T extends Model<T>>(this: new () => T) {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
}
```

But when I try to run it: `Property 'property' does not exist on type 'new () => T'. (2339)`

The only way to have the property recognized is to add `& typeof Model` in the method signature:

```
class Model<T extends Model<T>> {
  static property;

  static method<T extends Model<T>>(this: (new () => T) & typeof Model) {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
}
```

But in this way `this` can also be a subset of `T` and so returning something like `new this()` is not compatible with a returning type of `T`...

any ideas??

Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you intent to use it?

Comment: I think we need more information about what you're trying to do... what code you'd like to see compile and what code you'd like to see give errors.  Keep in mind that for the kind of generics that look like `interface X<Y extends X<Y>> {...Y...}` you would usually just use [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) in TypeScript and declare `interface X {...this...}` instead without generics.

Comment: @jcalz looks like you're the typescript watchman on SO lol. Respect.

Comment: Added more examples in the question... @jcalz

Answer (score 0):

**Edit in response to OP update**

Two things happen here

1. inherit from abstract class
2. infer type of `this` when invoke `User.method()`

```js
abstract class Model1 {
    static property: boolean = true;

    static method<T>(this: T): T extends new () => infer R ? R : any {
        console.log(this.property); // error, but ignore it, 

        // From this point on, 
        // We should use the type-casted `SubClass` instead of`this`

        // Personally prefer type-cast to `any`
        // Because both `Dog` and `User` can `extends Model1`
        // There's no way to know in advance
        const SubClass = this as any;

        // However, if you really need to see something about `Model1`
        // const SubClass = this as any as (typeof Model1);

        console.log(SubClass.property) // good

        // Since you do understand what you're doing
        // it's fine to simply ts-ignore the warning
        // @ts-ignore
        return new SubClass()

        // Final word, because you've declared full `method()` signature
        // ts is not inferring type of return value from function body
        // so we're good.
    }

    // also check the instance side
    inheritedProperty: number;
}


class User extends Model1 {
    email: string;
}

// both static side and instance side members are all inherited
// and the types are correct
const user = User.method();
user.inheritedProperty = 1; // good
user.email = 'foo'; // good
User.property = 101 // error
```

Still, I'd like to bring attention to the fact that, *static side of class* has very little to do with the class itself. The link I posted in original answer is worth reading to fully understand the concept.

---

**Original answer:**

For what (I guess) you're trying to do, following suffices

```js
class Model {
    static property;

    static method(this: typeof Model) {
        console.log(this.property);
    }
}
```

Also for ref, here's a quote from the [typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

> [...] a class has two sides to its type: the static side and the instance side. Generic classes are only generic over their instance side rather than their static side, so when working with classes, static members can not use the class’s type parameter.

Comment: This example lacks some things I'd like to have. Added in the original question...

Comment: Thanks @hackape yes, I've understood that the generics attached to the class has very little to do with the static class, I only need it for the constructor to limit the fields I can specify. Moreover I don't understand what you wrote in the updated code: I can't access `this.property` because `T` is nothing related to `Model1`, right? `method` should return (my fault, I've not specified it in the `Model1` code) a instance of the extended class (from `Model1`, `User1`)

Comment: @Zweer Updated again